# externalized configuration for multiple Spring war files in Jetty 9

Tags: configuration, spring-boot, war, jetty-9

We are building a large web app as several WAR files.  Each WAR file is a Spring Boot application.  For development and testing, we can run these WAR files independently.  But in production, we want to run all of the WAR files together under one instance of Jetty (9.x).

The question we have is, what is the best way to deal with externalized configuration in this scenario?  Each WAR file has its own set of configuration files (application.properties and others) that it needs.  How can we set things up so that each WAR file reads its own configuration files and ignores the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location` to give each application a distinct name and/or location for its external configuration files. I'd set these properties in the `configure` method that you've overriden in your `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work out better is to use the @PropertySources annotation on your [@SpringBootApplication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) class for each Spring Boot application.

For example,
You can then rename application.properties for each application, like app1.properties, app2.properties, and so on.

Then you can start up Jetty providing a common configuration folder
-Dapplication.home=C:/apphome

And in each @SpringBootApplication, add a @PropertySources annotation that looks like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:app1.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:${application.home}/app1/app1.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class App1Config {
...
}
```

In development, the app#.properties will be read. Then in production, when you define application.home, the application.home/app#/app#.properties [will override the one in the classpath](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)